# bash: in 1 script file execute multiple commands simultaneously in different terminals

Tags: windows, bash, terminal

I have a bash script file which main purpose is to (cross) compile binaries for several platforms.
What I want is simultaneously execute multiple commands (so start at the same time) in different terminals. To be clear they must be started (and closed) from the same (bash) .sh file.

I tried (just as test from the command prompt):
    gnome-terminal --title "terminal 1" -x bash -c "ssh -t root@192.x.y.z 'echo 1'"

but did not work; error msg: "Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:"
Of course gnome-terminal is installed.

Actually what I want in the (bash) sh file is:

(run in main terminal): command A; command B; command C

at the same time:
(run in terminal 2): command D, command E; command F (then close the terminal)

at the same time
(run in terminal 3): command G, command H; command I (then close the terminal)

when terminal 2 and 3 are finished and closed: execute rest of the .sh file

Comment: Do you need actual windows or processes are enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize background subshells and then a `wait`:

```
# A, B, C

(
    # D, E, F
) &

( 
    # G, H, I
) &

wait
```

Note that this sends all output to the main script's `stdout`. If you want to save the output of the subshells separately, use `(stuff) > file.log &` or `(stuff) | tee file.log &` for each.

Comment: I want to execute it from a shell script file (ssh mode) and then open and execute in more terminals at the same time, then close those 'extra' terminals and return to the main terminal. So no file saving etc.

Comment: I only brought up redirection in case you wish to save the output of those commands separately. If background subshells are insufficient and you for some reason literally need different windows, please refer to @thatotherguy's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is fine. The reason why it says "Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:" is because DISPLAY isn't set, so gnome-terminal doesn't know where to open a window. Are you perhaps trying to run the script from ssh, or from a GNU screen session started outside of X?

If you're running from ssh, you can use `ssh -X` to open the terminals on the client you ssh from. If you run in screen and/or want to open gnome-terminal on the first display on the box, `export DISPLAY=:0` in the beginning of your script.

If you want to open it on another display on the server (e.g. a NX or VNC session), open a terminal manually there, `echo $DISPLAY` to see which display number it is, and then set DISPLAY to that value in your script.

Comment: Tnx. I am running the script within/from a ssh terminal session.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to implement/use the -X, because

    gnome-terminal --title "terminal 1" -x bash -c "ssh -t root@192.x.y.z 'echo 1' -X"

did not work either

Comment: SSH -X works but it will open an other SSH session in the same window. I use putty to login by SSH and then run the shell script

Comment: Are you logging in using Putty on Windows, and want to open the gnome-terminals alongside your Putty window? If so, you have to run an X server for Windows, and have Putty forward to it. Here's a [guide using xming](http://www.math.umn.edu/systems_guide/putty_xwin32.html)

Comment: Wait... I am using putty on Windows to login to my local server, so everything is local (LAN). Why do I need X server, I thought that was for remote connecting

Comment: You always need an X server to show graphical apps, the question is where you want to run it: http://i.imgur.com/m1c4DH6.png